# How to extract meaning from sentences after running named entity recognition?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

First: Any recs on how to modify the title?

I am using my own named entity recognition algorithm to parse data from plain text.  Specifically, I am trying to extract lawyer practice areas.  A common sentence structure that I see is:

1) Neil focuses his practice on employment, tax, and copyright litigation.

or

2) Neil focuses his practice on general corporate matters including securities, business organizations, contract preparation, and intellectual property protection.

My entity extraction is doing a good job of finding the key words, for example, my output from sentence one might look like this:

Neil focuses his practice on (employment), (tax), and (copyright litigation).

However, that doesn't really help me.  What would be more helpful is if i got an output that looked more like this:

Neil focuses his practice on (employment - litigation), (tax - litigation), and (copyright litigation).

Is there a way to accomplish this goal using an existing python framework such as nltk (after my algo extracts the practice areas) can I use ntlk to extract the other words that my "practice areas" modify in order to get a more complete picture?

Comment: it's quite impossible by just using NLTK. You would need a paraphrase system, sense disambiguation system, some syntactic parsing and possibly reordering language models.

Answer (score 4):

[Named entity recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (NER) systems typically use grammer-based rules or statistical language models. What you have described here seems to be based only on keywords, though.

Typically, and much like most complex NLP tasks, NER systems should be trained on domain-specific data so that they perform well on previously unseen (test) data. You will require adequate knowledge of machine learning to go down that path.

In "normal" language, if you want to extract words or phrases and categorize them into classes defined by you (e.g. *litigation*), if often makes sense to use category labels in external ontologies. An example could be:

- You want to extract words and phrases related to sports.

Such a categorization (i.e. detecting whether or not a word is indeed related to sports) is not a "general"-enough problem. Which means you will not find ready-made systems that will solve the problem (e.g. algorithms in the NLTK library). You can, however, use an ontology like Wikipedia and exploit the category labels available there.

- E.g., you can check that if you search Wikipedia for "football", which has a category label "ball games", which in turn is under "sports".

Note that the wikipedia category labels form a directed graph. If you build a system which exploits the category structure of such an ontology, you should be able to categorize terms in your texts as you see fit. Moreover, you can even control the granularity of the categorization (e.g. do you want just "sports", or "individual sports" and "team sports").

I have built such a system for categorizing terms related to computer science, and it worked remarkably well. The closest freely available system that works in a similar way is the [Wikifier](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/demo_view/Wikifier) built by the cognitive computing group at the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign.

**Caveat**: You may need to tweak a simple category-based code to suit your needs. E.g. there is no wikipedia page for "litigation". Instead, it redirects you to a page titled "lawsuit". Such cases need to be handled separately.

**Final Note**: This solution is really not in the area of NLP, but my past experience suggests that for some domains, this kind of ontology-based approach works really well. Also, I have used the "sports" example in my answer because I know nothing about legal terminology. But I hope my example helps you understand the underlying process.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think your "algo" is even doing entity recognition... however, stretching the problem you presented quite a bit, what you want to do looks like coreference resolution in coordinated structures containing ellipsis. Not easy at all: start by googling for some relevant literature in linguistics and computational linguistics. I use the standard terminology from the field below.

In practical terms, you could start by assigning the nearest antecedent (the most frequently used approach in English). Using your examples:

- first extract all the "entities" in a sentence
- from the entity list, identify antecedent candidates ("litigation", etc.). This is a very difficult task, involving many different problems... you might avoid it if you know in advance the "entities" that will be interesting for you.
- finally, you assign (resolve) each anaphora/cataphora to the nearest antecedent.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I am self taught, so vocab is actually a bit of a challenge for me.  Quick question, what would you call what my program does if its not entity recognition?

Comment: If you are interested in this kind of problem you should get a handbook of NLP, computational linguistics, etc. from your local library. I seriously doubt anyone can produce good results on his/her own. Regarding your program: I cannot know what it is doing, so I will not name it... however, (Named) Entity Recognition assigns a label to each extracted entity, corresponding to a category of entities (person, country, company, protein, gene, etc.). Check the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CogComp NER tagger: 
https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/ner